# Ajax not working?

Tags: php, ajax

where did i go wrong? It should update mysql(insertsuscribe function) and change the image in the anchor tag.  This is my first time doing AJAX, what did i do wrong?

php

```
$id= $row['id'];
echo "<div class='suscribe'><a id='s$id' href='javascript:suscribe($id);'><img src='/suscribe.jpg' alt='suscribe' /></a></div>";
```

ajax

```
function suscribe(number)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("s"+number).innerHTML="<img src='/unsuscribe.jpg' alt='unsuscribe' />";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","suscribe.php?id="+number,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

suscribe.php

```
<?php  session_start();  
include "database.php";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$database = new Database();
$database->opendb();
$database->insertsuscribe($id);
$database->closedb();

?>
```

Comment: jQuery would make your life a lot easier. I'm not trying to say you can't do the AJAX yourself, but jQuery just makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks i'd still prefer the solution to the AJAX, to learn where i went wrong.

Comment: @user892134: Also, it is `subscribe` not `suscribe` and `unsuscribe`.

Comment: what exactly is not working as, the ajax part is working, except the typo. I suspect its within your database class, also what are you doing with just an id within the class..

Comment: In the class i use the $id to update the database. If the AJAX is working why isn't the image changing when i click the subscribe image?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the HMTL is valid. Ajax has issues if the html is not valid. Also if you are using firefox have you considered using a plugin such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ . This will help you identify if the issue is with the data not being sent, received or the page not updating.

Comment: ok i instaled firebug but no errors when i click? nothing happens? lol.. two things should happen. the image in the anchor tag should be changed and the database should be updated.